# The image doesn't get more wide

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, setinterval

I was trying to make a mini image editor with a width and height function. The image should keep getting more wide after button is clicked. I tried debugging with printing the width in the console and it did but the image didn't get wider. I also tried many other variations and all of them didn't work.

so, here is my code:

```
function go1(){
setInterval( function() {document.getElementById("testimage").style.width + 10}, 250)
}
```

Comment: If you take your age and add 5 does it make you 5 years older? You wanted you use `+=` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is that while you are calculating a new width, you are aren't setting the new width in your code.

The second problem is that IMG tags don't use the `width` style. Instead, they have a width attribute

```
function go1(){
  setInterval( function() {
    var im = document.getElementById("testimage");
    var newWidth = (im.getAttribute("width") ? im.getAttribute("width") : 0) + 10;
    im.setAttribute("width", newWidth);
  }, 250)
}
```

Comment: Got a new problem, it just waits 250 ms and then gets wider and stops. It actually should keep getting wider

Comment: @samuraiskiy set a break point in your interval function (or use `console.log`s) to debug

Comment: So it started working correctly, but the width is getting TOO big even when i wrote + 1 (i also tried 0.1)

Comment: @samuraiskiy so call clearInterval with the interval's ID when the width is big enough (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

Comment: @ControlAltDev I didn't mean that, i want it to add a smaller value to the width because i tried + 1 and it feels like its adding 10.

Comment: @samuraiskiy re: smaller value - I don't know what to tell you / I don't know how you could add less than 1... Maybe post a new question with an example that demonstrates the problem you are having?